# show a popup (UIAlertView) while iPhone app is running in background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new to iphone app development.

My question is how can I show a popup (UIAlertView) while my app is running in background?
I am using xcode 4.2 for ios 6
I am unable to find a satisfactory answer over the internet.
Can someone please help me with this?

```
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
      {
         UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
         bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
         }];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         NSTimer* t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(doBackgroundProcessing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    });
```

}

```
    - (void) doBackgroundProcessing
    {
        global = [lMGlobal getInstance];

        while(TRUE)
        {
            [self showAlertFor:@"Hello" andMessage:@"Wake up"];

            [NSThread sleepUntilDate:[lMGlobal getSleepDuration]];

        }

    }

    - (void) showAlertFor:(NSString *)title andMessage:(NSString*)message
      {
          UIAlertView *alertDialog;
          alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
               initWithTitle:title
               message:message
               delegate: self
               cancelButtonTitle: nil
               otherButtonTitles: @"Mute", nil];

          [alertDialog
          performSelector:@selector(show)
          onThread:[NSThread mainThread]
          withObject:nil
          waitUntilDone:NO];
          [alertDialog release];
      }
```

Comment: Why not YOU try UILoalNotification or POPUP notification by both way you show message on main screen when application running in background .i not think your given code in working at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you cannot show a UIAlertView, you could show a UILocalNotification. Your code could look something like this:

```
backupAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

backupAlarm.fireDate = alarmTime;
backupAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

backupAlarm.alertBody = @"Good morning, time to wake up.";
backupAlarm.alertAction = @"Show me";
backupAlarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works. They are visible under notification centre but the notification doesn't seem to popup. Is there a setting to make it pop?

Comment: I got it...You cant do much about it since you don't have any control over it...It is up to the user how he sets up Notification Center alert style under settings > notification...And to add to the misery Notification centre is not available in simulator :(

Comment: That is correct, it is up to the user as to how they display.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have your app show a `UIAlertView` while running in the background.

Comment: My app is running in background. Inside  applicationDidEnterBackground i am calling doBackgroundProcessing method

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it directly BUT you can **fire a UILocalNotification!**

Answer (score 0):

Furthemore the @DavidBrunow 's response, you have to schedule the configured local notification by:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: backupAlarm];
```